# How do i change one value in a csv file?

Tags: python

I want to just change a single value, do I have to make a whole new file? Say if I am collecting data about people and someones information changes or they want to change their password, what do I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change specific value in CSV file via Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033590/change-specific-value-in-csv-file-via-python)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to read it, change the specific line and write a new file or overwrite the old one.

Comment: how do I do this? I'm very new in python!!

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719438/editing-specific-line-in-text-file-in-python