# How can I change the text of my file after some commas into numbers in python?

Tags: python

Code:

```
f = open("iris.txt", "r")

**#w = write("iris.txt","w") --** 

print(f.read())
```

Text File:

```
4.6,3.2,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.3,3.7,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.3,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
7.0,3.2,4.7,1.4,Iris-versicolor
6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
6.9,3.1,4.9,1.5,Iris-versicolor
```

Example:
I want Iris-setosa = 0 and Iris-versicolor = 1, and there are multiple of setosa and versicolor in a line.

Output:

```
4.6,3.2,1.4,0.2,0
5.3,3.7,1.5,0.2,0
5.0,3.3,1.4,0.2,0
7.0,3.2,4.7,1.4,1
6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5,1
6.9,3.1,4.9,1.5,1
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change specific value in CSV file via Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033590/change-specific-value-in-csv-file-via-python)

Answer (score 0):

You should set the data into a pandas data frame and then use pd.get_dummies() on this column if you intend to create a classification model